# ¿Como hago para que al hacer click en una zona se despliegue un div desde el centro con jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Buenas. Tengo este código para desplegar el div tras hacer click en la foto de Stolen Kiss, adjunto foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer click en la foto quiero que se despliegue este div empezando desde el centro y expandiendose hacia arriba y abajo a la misma velocidad. 
Adjunto foto del div:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no he encontrado ningún comando ni forma de hacer que este aparezca como quiero, he probado con el fadeIn pero no es lo que busco. 
 No pongo mí código ya que este funciona como quiero, lo que quiero saber es si existe alguna función de jQuery que sirva para lo que pido ya que no he encontrado nada útil.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras mirar varios metodos diferentes un amigo me ha comentado que se usa el método animate(). El código ha quedado así finalmente:

```
            $("#wander").click(function(){                  
                $("#float").show();
                $("#float").animate({height:500},500);
                $("#div_negro").show();
            });
```

El atributo height tiene que estar definido en CSS desde que tamaño quieres que empieze. En el metodo animate el height es la altura a la que llegará el div float y el 500 de la izquierda son los milisegundos que tardará en hacerlo.

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras solucion. Tras 47h podrás marcar esta respuesta como aceptada. Como consejo, la proxima vez intenta e investiga un poco más de tiempo antes de preguntar :P Un saludo

Comment: Llevaba investigando bastante tiempo. Justo he coincidido con un compañero en la cafetería y el lo sabía. Me lo llego a encontrar antes y no ponía el post. Saludos.